# Sorting the result being displayed without merging the two arrays

Tags: java, jsp, sorting, servlets, struts

I have two arrays as follows in my form and I am displaying the values of the arrays to the user using jsp.

```
Trip[] tripArray = new Trip[];
Route[] routeArray = new Route[];


Trip Class: 
public class Trip{
    private String name; 
    private String address; 
    private String job; 
}

Route class: 
public class Route{
    private String myName; 
    private String myAddress;
    private String myJob; 
}
```

My jsp file:

```xml
<logic: notEmpty name="myForm" property="tripArray">
<logic:iterate id="data" name="myForm" property="tripArray" type="com.example.Trip">
    <td><bean:write name="data" property="name" /></td>
    <td><bean:write name="data" property="address"/></td>
    <td><bean:write name="data" property="job"/></td>
</logic:iterate>
</logic:notEmtpty>

<logic: notEmpty name="myForm" property="routeArray">
<logic:iterate id="data" name="myForm" property="routeArray" type="com.example.Route">
    <td><bean:write name="data" property="myName" /></td>
    <td><bean:write name="data" property="myAddress"/></td>
    <td><bean:write name="data" property="myJob"/></td>
</logic:iterate>
</logic:notEmtpty>
```

I want to able to sort the results thats' being displayed. Since I have two arrays, I can merge the two arrays, sort it and display the results using the new merged array.

But this would require me to change my jsp file as well. And I believe it's just too much work than necessary doing it this way.

Is there another way to do this without having to change my jsp file and without merging the arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Arrays.sort to sort an array:

```
    String[] examples = new String[] {"test", "a", "long one", "", "one was blank (this is longest)"};
    Arrays.sort(examples, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) {
            if(arg0.length() < arg1.length())
                return -1;
            if(arg0.length() > arg1.length())
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }

    });
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(examples));
```

Will have the output:

```
[, a, test, long one, one was blank (this is longest)]
```

The comparator I set up there is set to have shortest ones first, longest last; you can adjust the comparator however you want though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have two arrays that needs to be sorted without merging them. Can that be done?

Comment: What do you mean? Just sort them each separately..?

Comment: sorting them separately and displaying them wouldn't be a sorted result in the UI screen. I want to somehow show the values of the two arrays sorted in the UI without merging the arrays. I hope that makes sense

Comment: Could you make a new array, merge them into that, sort that new array, and display that?

Comment: I thought about that but that would mean I would have to change my jsp file. Can I do it without merging the two arrays?

Comment: Why would you have to change your jsp file? Just take the arrays, merge them via java, into a new array, print out that one sorted

Comment: Thanks Alex. As you can see from my jsp page above, i have two loops iterating through the array. So merging the two arrays would need only one loop. Although I do like your answer, is there some struts function or jsp function that would just do the sorting automatically, without me having to merge it manually?

Comment: Object[] merged = ArrayUtils.addAll(first, second);